# HBaseAdmin isMasterRunning() replacement

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

In Hbase .98 , we were using [`.isMasterRunning()`](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/ClusterConnection.html#isMasterRunning()) to see if HBase was running, and if it was, we could create tables successfully.  Now in 1.1.1 it's been deprecated... is there a good workaround to see if HBase is up and running so we can start creating/writing to tables?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [Admin](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Admin.html#getClusterStatus()): `connection.getAdmin().getClusterStatus().getMaster() != null`, any exceptions raised by the expression above most probably mean that creating/writing to tables won't succeed as well.

Alternatively you don't need to check at all and just handle errors from the code that create/write to tables.